# How to get JavaScript query to display results in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

Hey I'm trying to get the results of my query to display on my webpage, how can I get that to happen?

I'm running this on oddschecker pages like: http://www.oddschecker.com/horse-racing/thirsk/14:00/winner through a json.manifest, so I want to be able to run this through a chrome extension, how can I get the javascript function to display as a html page??

```
<html>
<title>I am not very good.</title>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
var odds = $('.co');
odds.each(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if(id.indexOf('_B3') >= 0){
        console.log(id);
        //your code here
    }
});}
</script>
 </head>
<body>
<div id="oddschecker"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So where are your `.co` elements?

Comment: They're on the oddschecker website, if you right click one of the odds elements it has them beside it

Comment: http://i.gyazo.com/63c7a3e2d93918e727c73aea0a7ebbd6.png

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "display as an html page"?  Are you trying to inject content into that page?  If so you can just append to the DOM, but it isn't clear if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Essentially I'm trying to create a chrome extension, which will run this javascript on whatever page I have currently open

Comment: Start with the [Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview), please, esp. the architecture part. putvande is correct; there's no `.co` element in your document, you can't just refer to another page like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <title>I am not very good.</title> 

    <head> 
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
        var odds = $('.co');
        odds.each(function() {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');

            if(id.indexOf('_B3') >= 0) {
                console.log(id);
                $('#oddschecker').html(data); // data is the retrieval data
            }
        });
     }
     </script> 
</head> 
<body>
    <div id="oddschecker"></div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know if this works as it outputs nothing when I run it when on

This is the manifest.json file I have for chrome: 

{
 "name": "Oddschecker",
 "version": "1.0",
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "description": "Calculates the average payout of Oddschecker Odds",

 "browser_action": {
 "default_icon": "icon.png",
 "default_popup": "index.html"
  }
}

The default popup is the index.html file above, but it doesn't do anything when I run it Saravanan